# Installing pdf-tools on Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, pdf-tools

I am new to Emacs and I am trying to install `pdf-tools` on Windows. I am following [this](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/blob/master/README.org#compilation-and-installation-on-windows), but I just couldn't understand what to do from the step 3. Could someone explain to me in very simple language what to do? I have very little experience and don't really understand this language.

[image]

Comment: For the start, do `echo $PATH` in that shell and see if the directory to `emacs.exe` appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Emacs and cask installed before compiling pdf-tools.

```
pacman -S python
pacman -S git
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cask/cask/master/go | python
git clone https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools
cd pdf-tools/
export PATH=/home/<your username>/.cask/bin:/c/emax64/bin:$PATH
make -s
```

Even then the build process might fail once or twice. If you can't get it to work, download just the pdf-tools melpa repo compiled for 64-bit Emacs on Windows here: https://github.com/m-parashar/emax64/releases/tag/20180529

PS: I maintain the emax64 distribtion, which comes with imagemagick7 and pdf-tools and other packages (emax.7z) pre-compiled and ready to use: https://github.com/m-parashar/emax64